# Woocommerce woocommerce_breadcrumb_defaults filter

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

i was just struggle for hours now trying to deal with the breadcrumb of woocommerce, I just saw that with a normal function it doesnt work..

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_breadcrumb_defaults', 'custom_breadcrumb');

function custom_breadcrumb() {
    return array(
        'delimiter'   => '<li class="mx-2 text-gray-500">/</li>',
        'wrap_before' => '<ol class="breadcrumb flex text-xs uppercase text-gray-400 font-medium">',
        'wrap_after'  => '</ol>',
        'before'      => '<li class="hover:text-blue-500">',
        'after'       => '</li>',
        'home'        => _x( 'Home', 'breadcrumb', 'woocommerce' ),
    );
}
```

but the closure one bellow works

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_breadcrumb_defaults', function() {
    return array(
        'delimiter'   => '<li class="mx-2 text-gray-500">/</li>',
        'wrap_before' => '<ol class="breadcrumb flex text-xs uppercase text-gray-400 font-medium">',
        'wrap_after'  => '</ol>',
        'before'      => '<li class="hover:text-blue-500">',
        'after'       => '</li>',
        'home'        => _x( 'Home', 'breadcrumb', 'woocommerce' ),
    );
} );
```

Anyone can explain why it doesnt work or where i failed?

Comment: The only reason the first one wouldn't work, if the second one does, is if there's already a function called `custom_breadcrumb()` somewhere on your site. Try changing it to something more unique, to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad.. it was the namespace

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_breadcrumb_defaults', 'mynamespace\\custom_breadcrumb');
```